# Keyboard not getting dismissed when MDTimePicker is shown

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, timepicker

[image: **enter image description here**]

I got problem while showing timer picker. There are two text fields: 1. first one opens a number pad. 2. second opens time picker from material controls.
Once I start editing first TF & if I tap on second TF the number pad is not getting dismissed even if I tap on Done button.
the done button is created using ToolBar & the method contains "view.endEditing" code. It works fine normally but not in above condition.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    rateInPointsTextField.delegate = self
}

extension MyAvailabilityVC : UITextFieldDelegate{
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()

    //done button for toolbaar
    let done = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(donePressed))
    toolbar.setItems([done], animated: false)

    self.rateInPointsTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar



@objc func donePressed(){
    self.view.endEditing(true)

}



func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    if textField == self.fromTimeTextField{

        let timePicker = MDTimePickerDialog()
        timePicker.delegate = self
        timePicker.tag = 100
        timePicker.clockMode = .mode12H
        timePicker.show()
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    self.rateInPointsTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Confirm  `UITextFieldDelegate` in your view controller & set TF delegate to self

```swift
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var your_tf: UITextField!
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        your_tf.delegate = self;

   }
   ....

  func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

}
```

Now when you will press done/return button of keyboard then keyboard will dismiss. If you want to dismiss from your created button then make call from done @Action fun to `textFieldShouldReturn(your_tf)` like this.

```swift
...
@objc func donePressed(){
    textFieldShouldReturn(your_tf)

}
```

Comment: try this call `textFieldShouldReturn(your_tf)` from `donePressed()` I tried & it is working.

Comment: I tried that but still not working & getting a warning "Result of call to 'textFieldShouldReturn' is unused"

Comment: Warning is because textFieldShouldReturn Bool but we are not using that but not working means you're application's others views causing this issue try removing all constraints & then try.